# Generate numbers with only given X,Y Z up to N?

Tags: algorithm

This question was asked in paypal interview.

Basically lets assume `x < y < z` and `0 <= x,y,z <10`. Given x, y, z generate all combination of x, y , z and push it a list. where the returned list should be in sorted order.

example -> `let x,y,z = 1,2,3`.

output would be `[1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 133, 211 ... ,331, 332, 333]`

Brute Force solution should not be applied.

Here is my brute force solution, which was not considered

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
let stack = [];
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  stack.push(arr[i] + "");
  for(let j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
    stack.push(arr[i] + "" + arr[j]);
    for(let k=0; k<arr.length; k++){
      stack.push(arr[i] + "" + arr[j] + "" + arr[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've done and specify the language you are trying to solved it.
Please read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have no idea whether your solution is brute force or not, but it produces wrong output.

Comment: And in sorted order is numeric or lexicographic? if numeric your brute force is wrong it generate 1,11,111 before anything else.

Comment: Yep this output is wrong, basically they want the sorted array by number as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution implemented in PHP. It can directly compute the nth element of the sequence:

```php
function getElement($i, $digits)
{
    $s = '';
    do
    {
        $r = $i % 3;
        $s = $digits[$r] . $s;
        $i = ($i - $r) / 3 - 1;
    }
    while($i>=0);
    return $s;
}

$digits = ['1', '2', '3'];
$max = 3 + 3*3 + 3*3*3;
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
    echo getElement($i, $digits) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
111
112
113
121
122
123
131
132
133
211
212
213
221
222
223
231
232
233
311
312
313
321
322
323
331
332
333
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats happening in do while loop and also if you can mention time complexity that would be great

Comment: @NithinJain The algorithm is very close to a base conversion (conversion to base 3). At every iteration, the remainder modulo 3 is taken to obtain the next digit.

Comment: @NithinJain As for the time complexity, I would say it's O(n log n) to compute the first n elements.